# Pressing Button with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to press a button with selenium. The page comes up, but it does not press the button. I am new to this, and also the page as a GEO block for any one in the UK. I am using a windows 10 laptop.

This is the code I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'G:/scraping_practice/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.maxpreps.com/tx/basketball/21-22/stat-leaders/scoring/ppg/')

search_button = driver.find_element(By.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[2]/button'))
search_button.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element with text ***2*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='controls']//ul/li/button[text()='2']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: So I just need to copy and paste the XPath into my code and then I am good?

Comment: @jarmoc07 Were you doing something else?